# Changing speed (duration) on animation/stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, duration

Had a look around and couldn't find an answer. I need to add the duration of animation to this code:

```
$('a:has(.image-active)').hover(function() { 
    $('.image-active', this).stop().animate({"opacity": 1}); 
},function() { 
    $('.image-active', this).stop().animate({"opacity": 0}); 
});
```

However, I can't work out where to place the duration. Just now it fades in to 1 and fades out to 0 which must be the default for jQuery.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the duration as the second parameter to animate(), for ex:

```
.animate({"opacity": 1}, "fast");
```

or

```
.animate({"opacity": 1}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) has a parameters object:

```
.animate({"opacity": 1}, {duration: 100});
```

I like being verbose, but you could also pass the duration as a number:

```
.animate({"opacity": 1}, 100);
```

Read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more options. Look at the examples.

Answer (score 0):

The [jquery API for the .animate() method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) is a great place to start. You can specify a duration (either as a millisecond value, or the 'fast' or 'slow' string) for the animation, after the properties. The default is 400, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `opacity` should not be in `quotes` change `"opacity"` to `opacity`

```
.animate({opacity: 1},100);
```

refer [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)